# Git, i pushed commit from local master branch to remote master branch, but the result is pushed to other branch

Tags: git, sourcetree

Is this git's bug? Because I couldn't have pushed to remote branchA because I even didn't checkout it to local branchA, so how could I pushed it to remote branchA

Comment: Give the commands you tried

Comment: i didnt use any commands, i used my sourcetree tool